# I keep getting ImportError every time I try running my kivymd code

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I just installed the kivymd master version on my windows system and upon trying to run my code I keep on getting ImortError: DDL load failed while trying to import celebs... Please can anyone help out

I hope someone can help me out